# How to filter file names by date/time?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, datetime

I need help in filtering specific time/dates(all files are in .jpeg format) in my program's report generation (motion detection system) in which the user can view detected images from a specific point of time to another (e.g. 1:00pm - 2:00pm) then display the files in the listbox.

[image]
sample screenshot **filename: pic_HHMMss_ddMMMyyyy**

The system works like this. After a motion is detected by the webcam, it automatically captures an image and save it to C:\Surveillance System\Detected and generate the filename pic_HHMMss_ddMMMyyyy. So this is now the report generation form wherein the authorized person can view detected images by filtering the time/date of which when the photo is captured.

For now, I can only display all the files in the directory without any filters. Any insights or help is greatly appreciated. Thanks! :)
codes:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    ' make a reference to a directory
    Dim di As New IO.DirectoryInfo("c:\Surveillance System\Detected")
    Dim diar1 As IO.FileInfo() = di.GetFiles()
    Dim dra As IO.FileInfo

    'list the names of all files in the specified directory
    For Each dra In diar1
        ListBox1.Items.Add(dra)
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("C:\Surveillance System\Detected\" & ListBox1.Text)
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    DateTimePicker2.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Time
    DateTimePicker2.ShowUpDown = True
    DateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Time
    DateTimePicker1.ShowUpDown = True
End Sub
```

button1_click = show detected
button2_click = clear items

Comment: Add you existing code to show the list.

Comment: Are you using the date from the file name, or the created date from the file system?

Comment: i have timestamped & datestamped the filename on when it was detected..so the time/date are from the system..

Answer (score 6):

There are two ways to do this. One is by the time listed as part of the file name:

```
Function GetFiles(ByVal FilterStart As DateTime, ByVal FilterEnd As DateTime) As IEnumerable(Of String)
    Dim culture As CultureInfo = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
    Dim FormatString As String = "HHmmss_ddMMMyyyy"
    Return Directory.EnumerateFiles("c:\Surveillance System\Detected") _
        .Where(Function(f)
                   Dim Filedate As DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(f.Replace("pic_", "").Replace(".jpeg", ""), FormatString, culture)
                   Return Filedate >= FilterStart AndAlso Filedate <= FilterEnd
               End Function)
End Function
```

---

**Update:**
I see you changed the picture. The format string provided here only supports original file name format used in the original picture. The new picture shows multiple conventions for the file name format. If you are really going to have multiple kinds of names for your files, you should consider using the Created Date option below, or extend this option to use the [`TryParseExact()` overload that accepts an array of possible formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h9b85w22.aspx).

---

The other is to use the Created Date information from the file system:

```
Function GetFiles(ByVal FilterStart As DateTime, ByVal FilterEnd As DateTime) As IEnumerable(Of String)      
    Dim di As New DirectoryInfo("c:\Surveillance System\Detected")
    Return di.EnumerateFileSystemInfos() _
        .Where(Function(f) f.CreationTime >= FilterStart AndAlso f.CreationTime <= FilterEnd) _
        .Select(Function(f) f.Name)
End Function
```

Comment: ty sir for the insight, but where should I put these codes? Im sorry -newbie here.

Comment: @jovski, this would replace what's in your `Button1_Click` method.

Comment: I've replaced my Button1_click codes with this one but it wont accept it. what am i doing wrong? pardon me :)

Comment: Use this in your Button1_click in place of `diar1`. You'll need to pass Start and End times to the function to filter the dates.

Comment: This code may not work because you need to add `Imports System.Linq` ,`Imports System.IO` and `Imports System.Globalization` above your class.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `GetAttributes` on your files

see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.getattributes(v=vs.110).aspx

**EDIT**
This will add files created between the two times you set in your `DateTimePicker`. This will work if you want filter on when the file was created, otherwise you need to do some text transformations to `dra.FileName` to match it to your filenames. You would also want to add an event to track changes in the `DateTimePicker`s so your list will automatically filter and update

```
'list the names of all files in the specified directory
    For Each dra In diar1
        If dra.CreationTime > DateTimePicker1.Value And dra.CreationTime < DateTimePicker2.Value Then
            ListBox1.Items.Add(dra)
        End If
    Next
```

If you want use the filename then you need to the extract date and convert the text to date so you can file based on the `DateTimePicker`

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click


       DateTimePicker_ValueChanged(sender,Nothing)
End Sub


Private Sub DateTimePicker_ValueChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles  DateTimePicker1.ValueChanged, DateTimePicker2.ValueChanged


    Dim di As New IO.DirectoryInfo("c:\Surveillance System\Detected")
    Dim diar1 As IO.FileInfo() = di.GetFiles()
    Dim dra As IO.FileInfo

    ListBox1.Items.Clear()
    'list the names of all files in the specified directory
    For Each dra In diar1

        'Get file name and then convert to time
        Dim splitname As String() = Replace(dra.Name.ToString, ".jpeg", "").Split("_")
        Dim filetime As DateTime = Date.ParseExact(splitname(2) & splitname(1), "ddMMMyyyyHHmmss", System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo)

        If filetime > DateTimePicker1.Value And filetime < DateTimePicker2.Value Then
            ListBox1.Items.Add(dra)

        End If
    Next

end Sub
```

Comment: Probably you meant `File.GetCreationTime` but I think our friend wants to filter by file name which already has the date/time because the creation date of the file may vary if they are copied from one directory to another

Comment: to clarify what im asking, i will tell you how my system works, after a motion is detected by the camera, it will capture an image then save it to C:\surveillance system\detected and the filename would be "pic_(timehere)_(datehere)"..

Comment: hmm sorry but can you tell me what text transformation should I do? I mean changing the filename itself?

Comment: tnx for the heads up, but where should I put in this codes? I do get the logic but I dont really know where to put in the codes..sorry :D

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean... but the bottom bit of code if you paste it in where your `Button1_Click` method is, this code will filter your list when someone hits `Button1` or changes the dates in the pickers

Comment: I mean when I pasted the code in the button1_click, it looks for the DateTimePicker_valuechanged control, of which my program didnt have (it only have DateTimePicker1 and DateTimePicker2)

Comment: This code doesn't reference a `DateTimePicker_valuechanged` control, it references a method that catches changes to `DateTimePicker1` and `DateTimePicker2` called `DateTimePicker_valuechanged`. Did you copy both methods over your original `Button1_Click`

Comment: hello sir, i put the codes in the "filter" button which is button3_click..but unfortunately its not working

Comment: what doesn't work? I cant see your errors or what fails to run?

Comment: when I click the button, no file is added in the listbox..no errors or whatever showed upon clicking

Comment: go to http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47767/discussion-between-pt000-and-jovski ill try help you there. This is getting too long